# Need tall QED symbol

Tags: symbols

I need this tall QED symbol. Yes, need.

[image: Tall QED]

Here is an MWE, since my question was too short to meet quality standards.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\noindent In view of the choice we made for the orientation of $\partial D$, we conclude that 
\[\int_{\partial \mathbf{D}} \iota^*\omega = 
(-1)^n \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} a_n(\cdot,\cdot, \dots, \cdot, 0).\]
This completes the proof of the theorem. $\square$

\end{document}
```

Obviously the square should be replaced with the tall QED symbol. Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: I usually use `\square` or `\blacksquare`. Why do you need the tall one? Is the tall one common in you context? Which context is that? Is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: @moose -- this looks to me like an attempt to reproduce a historical document.  this style was typical in the late 1800s and early 1900s.

Comment: I just prefer the style, I was joking about needing it. And the book is from the late 60s.

Comment: `{\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\fbox{\phantom{l}}}` ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGW3U.png))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, I just scaled the `\square` in the vertical direction by a factor of 1.5 times the width, and called it `\tallqed`.  The `\smash` prevents it from affecting line spacing.  EDITED to reduce size.  Note that first argument of `\scalebox` is the horizontal scaling, while 2nd (optional) argument is the vertical scaling.  These can be adjusted to suit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}
\def\tallqed{\smash{\scalebox{.75}[1.125]{$\square$}}}
\begin{document}

\noindent In view of the choice we made for the orientation of $\partial D$, we conclude that 
\[\int_{\partial \mathbf{D}} \iota^*\omega = 
(-1)^n \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} a_n(\cdot,\cdot, \dots, \cdot, 0).\]
This completes the proof of the theorem. \tallqed
\end{document}
```

[image]

WChargin correctly points out that the symbol stretch makes the box border thickness non-uniform on the sides compared with the top/bottom.  If that is an issue, the problem can be remedied with a slightly altered definition, by `\ooalign`ing two of the stretched `\square`s with a slight kern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}
\def\tallqedX{\smash{\scalebox{.75}[1.125]{$\square$}}}
\def\tallqed{\ooalign{\tallqedX\cr\kern.2pt\tallqedX}}
\begin{document}

\noindent In view of the choice we made for the orientation of $\partial D$, we conclude that 
\[\int_{\partial \mathbf{D}} \iota^*\omega = 
(-1)^n \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} a_n(\cdot,\cdot, \dots, \cdot, 0).\]
This completes the proof of the theorem. \tallqed
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's too tall; I think 0.6/1.0 is fine, though.

Comment: @fctaylor25 I agree, and I have scaled it back.

Comment: @fctaylor25 Sorry, I was editing to explain how scaling can be tailored (or fctaylor'ed) to suit.

Comment: But this makes the top and bottom borders of the box heavier than the left and right borders. [See a zoomed-in image here.](https://i.imgur.com/QOHm4OS.png)

Comment: @WChargin True, but if that is an issue, it can be remedied with something akin to `\def\tallqedX{\smash{\scalebox{.75}[1.125]{$\square$}}}\def\tallqed{\ooalign{\tallqedX\cr\kern.2pt\tallqedX}}`.

Answer (score 7):

I'd use `amsthm` and its automatic `\qed` feature. But if you want, you can use `\tallopenbox` by itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}

\newcommand{\tallopenbox}{\leavevmode
  \hbox to.4em{%
  \hfil\vrule
  \vbox to.8em{\hrule width.3em\vfil\hrule}%
  \vrule\hfil}}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\tallopenbox}


\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
In view of the choice we made for the orientation of $\partial D$, we conclude that
\[
\int_{\partial \mathbf{D}} \iota^*\omega =
(-1)^n \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} a_n(\cdot,\cdot, \dots, \cdot, 0).
\]
This completes the proof of the theorem.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Modify the height (here `0.8em`) and the width (here `0.4em`); the inner width (here `.3em`) should a little smaller than the outer width.

Answer (score 2):

As a simple alternative to scaling the `\square`, consider employing a `\framebox` with a `\phantom` symbol:

`\def\tallqed{\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}\framebox{\phantom{t}}}`

You could customize the box thickness by adding, e.g., `\setlength{\fboxrule}{.3pt}` or pick another phantom symbol for adjusting the box size.

Answer (score 0):

Draw it manually:

```
\def\tallqed{\hbox{\rlap{\hbox{\vrule height 3mm width 0.1mm \hskip 1mm \vrule height 3mm width 0.1mm}}{\vbox
{\hrule height 0.1mm width 1.2mm \vskip 2.8mm \hrule height 0.1mm width 1.2mm}}}}    % tall q.e.d.

This completes the proof of the theorem. \hfill \tallqed
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 0):

The STIX font defines the mathemtical symbol `\vrectangle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}

$\vrectangle$

\end{document}
```

[image]